# how should I setting in spring-config.xml?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc

I use springmvc and my web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

so I can't use the External file such as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

My File structure is :[image]

I search a method is add this code in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml like this :`<mvc:resources mapping="/assests/js/**" location="WEB-INF/pages/assets/"/>` but it can't work! Is my path wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move your assets directory inside webapp directory and then change your configuration like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/assests/js/**" location="/assets/js/" />
```

Comment: but how should I change the link href in jsp document ? I can't import the file on a layer of documents

Comment: <script src="<c:url value="/assests/js/main.js" />"></script>